# Unique solvability of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

On page 18 of the book *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Wolfgang Walter the following example is presented:

$$y'=-x(sgn( y))\sqrt{|y|}= \begin{cases} 
      -x\sqrt{y} & \text{for } y\geq 0 \\
      x\sqrt{-y} & \text{for } y< 0 
   \end{cases},$$

whose solution is

$$y(x;C)=\frac{1}{16} (C-x^2)^2 \text{ in } (-\sqrt{C}, \sqrt{C}) \text{ } (C>0)$$

It is said that this function can be extended by setting $y(x;C)=0$ for $|x|\ge \sqrt{C}$, in which case the solution will be defined in $\mathbb{R}$. Then it is also said that there are no other solutions, since $g(y)=\sqrt{|y|}$ vanishes only for $y=0$. Thus each IVP with $y(\xi)=\eta\ne 0$ is locally uniquely solvable.

> I didn't understand from the above how it follows that $y(\xi)\ne 0$ is locally uniquely solvable.

Also, it is said that for the IVP with $y(\xi)=0$ there are infinitely many solutions in the case where $\xi \ne 0$, but only one solution in the case where $\xi=0$.

> I also didn't get how the above part follows for $\xi=0$ and $\xi \ne 0$.

Could someone please clarify the above two points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $g(y)=\text{sgn}(y)\sqrt{|y|}=0$ if and only if $y=0$. For the IVP with $y(\xi)=\eta\neq0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|y(x)|>\frac{|\eta|}2$ for $\forall x\in[\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta]$. Let $f(x,y)=xg(y)$ and then satisfies the Lipchitz condition about $y$. In fact, for $y_1,y_2$ with $|y_1|>\frac{|\eta|}2$ $|y_2|>\frac{|\eta|}2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\\
&=&|x||\sqrt{|y_1|}-\sqrt{|y_2|}|=|x|\frac{||y_1|-|y_2||}{\sqrt{|y_1|}+\sqrt{|y_2|}}\\
&\le&(|\xi|+\delta)\frac{|y_1-y_2|}{2\sqrt{\frac{\eta}{2}}}\\
&=&C|y_1-y_2|
\end{eqnarray*}
where
$$ C= \frac{(|\xi|+\delta)}{2\sqrt{\frac{\eta}{2}}}. $$
Then by the existence and uniqueness theorem, the IVP is solvable in $[\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta]$. This is what it means that the IVP with $y(\xi)=\eta\neq0$ is locally solvable.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you deduce that $|y(x)|>\frac{|\eta|}{2}$ implies that $f(x,y)=xg(y)$ is Lipschitz in $y$? $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|=|xg(y_1)-xg(y_2)|$ $=|x||\sqrt{y_1}-\sqrt{y_2}|$... Doesn't seem to give a clue how to proceed next.

Comment: @sequence, see the update.